# How is a Python code object marshalled at the C level?

Tags: python, object, python-3.5, bytecode

A post by [Ned Batchelder back in <sup>1</sup>2008](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html) made the claim the Python code objects are marshalled in Python bytecode files:

> [...] The entire rest of the file is just the output of [`marshal.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html#marshal.dump) of the code object that results from compiling the source file.

This may apply to code objects created at the Python level, but how exactly are these code objects marshalled at the C level?

I've looked over the documentation for [Python code objects(version 3.5)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/code.html),  and not much is said about them and certainly doesn't provide an information about how their marshalled:

> The C structure of the objects used to describe code objects. The fields of this type are subject to change at any time.

I've also tried to take a look at the [Python code object's source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/codeobject.c), but couldn't really find anything that answered my question.

If Python code objects are implemented using structs at the C level - which I believe they are - how then can they be marshalled into bytecode files? As far as the research I've done, C provides no built in methods for marshalling nor any third-party libraries?

If code objects are marshalled at the C level, how exactly is it done? If not, how *are* they encoded into the bytecode?

<sup>1</sup><sub>I especial noted the date because perhaps this detail has changed between Python versions</sub>.

Comment: "how exactly are these code objects marshalled at the C level?" - with `marshal.dump`, like it said. The C API for it goes by a slightly different name, but it's pretty much the same function. If you want to see the (deliberately undocumented) details of how `marshal.dump` works, you can [read the code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/marshal.c).

Comment: @user2357112 So they basically must implement a marshalling API from scratch?

Comment: Yup, just like they needed to do that for pickling. `marshal` is a Python-specific format for Python-specific data structures; there wasn't going to be some `mrshl` function in the C standard library that knows exactly what to do already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This may apply to code objects created at the Python level, but how exactly are these code objects marshalled at the C level?

With `marshal.dump`, or perhaps one of the related interfaces like `marshal.dumps`.

It's not as simple as "delegate to some C standard library function"; the marshalling and unmarshalling implementation comprises an [1820-line file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/marshal.c) you'd have to read if you want to see every detail. With how Python-specific its data structures and functionality are, most of the object tree traversal and serialization need to be written from scratch.